# Trying to write a struct content to a file but the file hasa random encoding

Tags: c, file, encoding, struct

I am trying to write the content of a struct to a specific file (created by code). I have two functions:

- One function writes struct X content to file X;
- One function writes struct Y content to file Y;

The functions have basically the same code, but the first one writes in ANSI encoding (what i want) and the second one writes in UCS-2 (not what i want)
Why is this specific function writing using the Wrong encoding ?

Function X

```
    ponteiro = fopen("DB_dispositivo.dat", "ab+");

dispositivo.id = id;
dispositivo.numero_serie = nserie;
strcpy(dispositivo.marca, marca);                   
strcpy(dispositivo.modelo, modelo);                 
strcpy(dispositivo.tipo, tipo);
strcpy(dispositivo.sistema_operativo, os);
dispositivo.ano = ano;

fwrite(&dispositivo, sizeof(dispositivo), 1, ponteiro);

fclose(ponteiro);
```

Function Y (the 'bad' one)

```
ponteiro = fopen("DB_software.dat", "ab+");

software.id = id;
software.numero_serie = numero_serie;
strcpy(software.nome, nome);                         
strcpy(software.versao, versao);                     
software.tamanho = tamanho;
software.tipo_licenca = tipo_licenca;
strcpy(software.data_validade, data_validade);

fwrite(&software, sizeof(software), 1, ponteiro);

fclose(ponteiro);
```

Any help will be appreciated !!

EDIT:

Struct X

```
struct dispositivos{            
    int id;
    int numero_serie;
    char marca[30];
    char modelo[30];
    char tipo[30];
    char sistema_operativo[30];
    int ano;
}dispositivo;
```

Struct Y:

```
struct softwares{               
    int id;
    int numero_serie;
    char nome[20];
    char versao[20];
    int tamanho; 
    int tipo_licenca;
    char data_validade[11];
}software;
```

Comment: How are the struts defined?

Comment: I'll edit my question with the structs, 1 sec

Comment: If your structs contain pointers, you should not be amazed. Also, you want to open for **r**eading using modes like ``"rb"``, not ``"ab+"``. Also, as ``b`` stands for binary, it is just like a ``memcpy``, i.e. there is no string related encoding. Probably the strings inside the struct you save are already encoded in different ways.

Comment: I'm "amazed" because the function X works out just fine, but the function Y writes with a different encoding. I would like to know why

Comment: What do you mean by "a random encoding" and "the second one writes in UCS-2"? You are using `char` arrays, each element is 1 byte. `fwrite` knows nothing about character encoding, it writes a block of data verbatim.

Comment: As u can see, both functions are identical. the values are identical (random numbers and text just to test them). When I open the 2 files created by my code, the 1º one is in ANSI encoding (what i want) and the 2º one is in UCS-2. Since i didnt specified nothing about that, why am i getting this encoding on this file ?

Comment: Then why does the 2º file have this encoding?

Comment: Time for a spot of debugging? Examine what you are filing, before you do so. Your codes are *not* identical, in that they do not use the same strings..

Comment: I finished examing my variables' content and they seem to me 'normal' (random numbers and words like "samsung", "windows", "pc" and "portal). However, i kinda managed to "fix" the problem by reordering the struct's variables - creating the char-type ones 1º.

Comment: Thanks for the attention

Comment: make sure you are typing in English and not in some language that uses English letters or letter that look like it.

Answer (score 0):

`fwrite(3)` just writes *the memory image* of the `struct` as a series of bytes.  By this reason, **data will be a binary sequence of bytes**, with possibly gaps for field alignment.  No encoding but the internal encoding for `int` and `char[]` is used.  Only the encoding you used at input (not shown) at the terminal, will be used for the string data input to the system.  And no encoding conversions are done in the `fread(3)` or `fwrite(3)` functions.

This data can only be read back in the same machine (or one with the same architecture) and with the `fread(3)` function, as the data format depends completely on how the compiler stores `struct` data internally in memory.

A different compiler, a different compiler version, a different machine endianness (the order in which integer bits are encoded in a larger than byte integer) can trash all your data forever.

I cannot recommend this kind of storage, if you are storing the data to interchange with other systems or even between different compiler versions.

If you observe data with different encodings for the char arrays, the most probable thing is that data already comes in different encodings.  `fwrite(3)` with the `a` modifier (contrary to `b` which means binary) only makes a difference in non-unix environments, like Windows or ms-dos, where `\n` characters are converted into `\r\n` sequences to comply with operating system's conventions for text file line delimiters.  And by this reason, **NEVER `fwrite(3)` a `struct` in text mode, as it is binary data**.